# How can I keep showing bottomNavigationBar in nested page?

Tags: flutter

there is shopping app, and there is 4 items in bottomNavBar.

[image]

in home page, fetch all categories and shown in page, when pressed on category, he should see the products in category. but how can I keep bottom navigation bar when I want to navigate him into next pages?

this is myBottomNavigationBar code:

```
Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            elevation: 0,
            actions: [
              IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.search,
                    color: Constants.blackBackgroundColor,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {})
            ],
          ),
          body: IndexedStack(
            index: _mainController.tabIndex,
            children: [
              HomePage(),
              OfferPage(),
              CartPage(),
              ProfilePage(),
            ],
          ),
          bottomNavigationBar: bottomNavigationBar(context),
        );
```

Comment: Assuming that you need to have a persistent bottom navigation, you can check this: https://pub.dev/packages/persistent_bottom_nav_bar

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62527739/keep-the-bottom-navigation-bar-in-every-screens-flutter This is the same case like you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if this is what you're looking for but here is one way of achieving it.

```
  List<dynamic> _screens = [ HomePage(), OfferPage(),CartPage(), ProfilePage()];

  int _index = 0;

  PageController controller = PageController();

Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            elevation: 0,
            actions: [
              IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.search,
                    color: Constants.blackBackgroundColor,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {})
            ],
          ),
          body: PageView.builder(
            itemCount: 4,
            controller: controller,
            onPageChanged: (page) {
              setState(() {
                _index = page;
              });
            },
            itemBuilder: (context, position) {
              return Container(
                color: Colors.white,
                child: Center(child: _screens[position]),
              );
            }),
          bottomNavigationBar: bottomNavigationBar(context),
        );
```

Comment: I used IndexedStack instead of pageview, and both should work fine, but if you push to new pages (navigator.push multiple time for multiple pages) then it doesn't work