# How to implement AppBar Drawer with bottom navigation bar in flutter bloc?

Tags: flutter, bloc

I am new to flutter bloc. I want to add side navigation drawer with bottom navigation. Can anyone help me how we can achieve this?

Comment: As per your requirement here is a link that you can achieve your requirement.
Link - https://prabhashibuddhima.medium.com/flutter-how-to-make-flutter-side-drawer-side-menu-work-with-bottom-navigation-bar-bottom-tab-ce66a95e25fe

Also, you can use the library to create a drawer with bottom navigation but it's an advanced level, although you can also learn it.
Link - https://pub.dev/packages/cuberto_bottom_bar

Comment: In this example. If i want to call another screen which is not in bottom navigation bar it crashed. There are only 5 main icon in bottom navigation bar and side navigation drawer has different page or screens to call. How we can do that?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/63446906/13418165

Comment: There is also navigation drawer in the appbar can we implement it with this example https://stackoverflow.com/a/63446906/13418165 ?

Comment: It would be better if anyone suggest solution using flutter bloc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize this code using the flutter bloc as well as per your requirement.

main.dart

```
import 'package:demo_app/custom_animated_bottom_bar.dart';
import 'package:demo_app/first_screen.dart';
import 'package:demo_app/fourth_screen.dart';
import 'package:demo_app/home_screen.dart';
import 'package:demo_app/messages_screen.dart';
import 'package:demo_app/profile_screen.dart';
import 'package:demo_app/second_screen.dart';
import 'package:demo_app/third_screen.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

enum ScreenType {
  firstScreen,
  secondScreen,
  thirdScreen,
  forthScreen,
  home,
  messages,
  profile
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  ScreenType _screenType = ScreenType.home;
  final _inactiveColor = Colors.grey;

  GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(getTitle(_screenType)),
      ),
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: ListView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          children: <Widget>[
            DrawerHeader(
              child: Text('Drawer Header'),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text('First Screen'),
              onTap: () => onTabTapped(ScreenType.firstScreen),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text('Second Screen'),
              onTap: () => onTabTapped(ScreenType.secondScreen),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text('Third Screen'),
              onTap: () => onTabTapped(ScreenType.thirdScreen),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: _body(_screenType),
      bottomNavigationBar: _buildBottomBar(),
    );
  }

  Widget _body(ScreenType screenType) {
    switch (screenType) {
      case ScreenType.firstScreen:
        return FirstScreen(
          voidCallback: () => onTabTapped(ScreenType.forthScreen),
        );
      case ScreenType.secondScreen:
        return const SecondScreen();
      case ScreenType.thirdScreen:
        return const ThirdScreen();
      case ScreenType.forthScreen:
        return const ForthScreen();
      case ScreenType.home:
        return const HomeScreen();
      case ScreenType.messages:
        return const MessagesScreen();
      case ScreenType.profile:
        return const ProfileScreen();
    }
  }

  Widget _buildBottomBar() {
    return CustomAnimatedBottomBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      selectedIndex: _screenType,
      showElevation: true,
      itemCornerRadius: 24,
      curve: Curves.easeIn,
      onItemSelected: onTabTapped,
      items: <BottomNavyBarItem>[
        BottomNavyBarItem(
          screenType: ScreenType.home,
          icon: Icon(Icons.apps),
          title: Text('Home'),
          activeColor: Colors.green,
          inactiveColor: _inactiveColor,
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),
        BottomNavyBarItem(
          screenType: ScreenType.messages,
          icon: Icon(Icons.message),
          title: Text('Messages'),
          activeColor: Colors.purpleAccent,
          inactiveColor: _inactiveColor,
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),
        BottomNavyBarItem(
          screenType: ScreenType.profile,
          icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle_rounded),
          title: Text('Profile'),
          activeColor: Colors.pink,
          inactiveColor: _inactiveColor,
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  void onTabTapped(ScreenType screenType) {
    if ((_scaffoldKey.currentState ?? ScaffoldState()).isDrawerOpen) {
      (_scaffoldKey.currentState ?? ScaffoldState()).openEndDrawer();
    }
    setState(() {
      _screenType = screenType;
    });
  }

  String getTitle(ScreenType screenType) {
    switch (screenType) {
      case ScreenType.firstScreen:
        return "First Screen";
      case ScreenType.secondScreen:
        return "Second Screen";
      case ScreenType.thirdScreen:
        return "Third Screen";
      case ScreenType.forthScreen:
        return "Forth Screen";
      case ScreenType.home:
        return "Home";
      case ScreenType.messages:
        return "Messages";
      case ScreenType.profile:
        return "Profile";
    }
  }
}
```

custom_animated_bottom_bar.dart

```
import 'package:demo_app/main.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class CustomAnimatedBottomBar extends StatelessWidget {
  CustomAnimatedBottomBar({
    Key? key,
    this.selectedIndex = ScreenType.home,
    this.showElevation = true,
    this.iconSize = 24,
    this.backgroundColor,
    this.itemCornerRadius = 40,
    this.animationDuration = const Duration(milliseconds: 270),
    this.mainAxisAlignment = MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    required this.items,
    required this.onItemSelected,
    this.curve = Curves.linear,
  })  : assert(items.length >= 2 && items.length <= 5),
        super(key: key);

  final ScreenType selectedIndex;
  final double iconSize;
  final Color? backgroundColor;
  final bool showElevation;
  final Duration animationDuration;
  final List<BottomNavyBarItem> items;
  final ValueChanged<ScreenType> onItemSelected;
  final MainAxisAlignment mainAxisAlignment;
  final double itemCornerRadius;
  final Curve curve;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final bgColor = backgroundColor ?? Theme.of(context).bottomAppBarColor;

    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: bgColor,
        boxShadow: [
          if (showElevation)
            const BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.black12,
              blurRadius: 2,
            ),
        ],
      ),
      child: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          height: kToolbarHeight,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 6, horizontal: 8),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: mainAxisAlignment,
            children: items.map((item) {
              var index = item;
              return GestureDetector(
                onTap: () => onItemSelected(index.screenType),
                child: _ItemWidget(
                  item: item,
                  iconSize: iconSize,
                  isSelected: index.screenType == selectedIndex,
                  backgroundColor: bgColor,
                  itemCornerRadius: itemCornerRadius,
                  animationDuration: animationDuration,
                  curve: curve,
                ),
              );
            }).toList(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _ItemWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final double iconSize;
  final bool isSelected;
  final BottomNavyBarItem item;
  final Color backgroundColor;
  final double itemCornerRadius;
  final Duration animationDuration;
  final Curve curve;

  const _ItemWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.item,
    required this.isSelected,
    required this.backgroundColor,
    required this.animationDuration,
    required this.itemCornerRadius,
    required this.iconSize,
    this.curve = Curves.linear,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Semantics(
      container: true,
      selected: isSelected,
      child: AnimatedContainer(
        width: isSelected ? 130 : 50,
        height: double.maxFinite,
        duration: animationDuration,
        curve: curve,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color:
              isSelected ? item.activeColor.withOpacity(0.2) : backgroundColor,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(itemCornerRadius),
        ),
        child: Container(
          width: isSelected ? 130 : 50,
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
          child: Row(
            // mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              IconTheme(
                data: IconThemeData(
                  size: iconSize,
                  color: isSelected
                      ? item.activeColor.withOpacity(1)
                      : item.inactiveColor == null
                          ? item.activeColor
                          : item.inactiveColor,
                ),
                child: item.icon,
              ),
              if (isSelected)
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4),
                    child: DefaultTextStyle.merge(
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: item.activeColor,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                      maxLines: 1,
                      textAlign: item.textAlign,
                      child: item.title,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BottomNavyBarItem {
  BottomNavyBarItem({
    required this.screenType,
    required this.icon,
    required this.title,
    this.activeColor = Colors.blue,
    this.textAlign,
    this.inactiveColor,
  });

  final ScreenType screenType;
  final Widget icon;
  final Widget title;
  final Color activeColor;
  final Color? inactiveColor;
  final TextAlign? textAlign;
}
```

first_screen.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class FirstScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const FirstScreen({
    Key? key,
    required this.voidCallback,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final VoidCallback voidCallback;

  @override
  _FirstScreenState createState() => _FirstScreenState();
}

class _FirstScreenState extends State<FirstScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Center(
        child: Flex(
          direction: Axis.vertical,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text("First Screen"),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: widget.voidCallback,
              child: Text("Go To Forth Screen"),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

second_screen.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SecondScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const SecondScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Center(
        child: Text("Second Screen"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

third_screen.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ThirdScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const ThirdScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Center(
        child: Text("Third Screen"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

forth_screen.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ForthScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const ForthScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Center(
        child: Text("Fourth Screen"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

home_screen.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Center(
        child: Text("Home Screen"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

messages_screen.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MessagesScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const MessagesScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Center(
        child: Text("Messages Screen"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

profile_screen.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ProfileScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const ProfileScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Center(
        child: Text("Profile Screen"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Suppose if there is a button on first screen and onclick of that button it should navigate to forth screen. how we can achieve that? and appbar should show title of navigated screen? above example is working as required. just need this two.

Comment: I tried adding button to first screen but when i click that button it opens fourth screen  outside the screen means bottom navigation and appbar doesn't shows.

Comment: As per requirement, you can also split the code in other ways.

Comment: Thank you so much Maulik it help me a lot.

Comment: How we can pass data? suppose there is a listview in second screen and want to show data in next screen on listview item click?

Comment: Okay, I have also tried with two button on first page. I am unable to figure out how we can handle that voidcallback for both button to navigates separately like first navigate to forth Screen and second navigates to fifth screen.

Comment: let's connect on skype and the id is "live:maulik.gajjar"

Comment: Thanks, Its okay don't want to disturb you more. This much help is enough ill find the solution.

Comment: Ok, no problem.But if you need help then feel free to contact me.

Comment: Can we pass data without using navigator.push ? as in above example there is no navigator used.

Comment: Connect on skype and help you with remote access